# What is the Strongly Typed version of CurrentPage.Id?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am using Umbraco CMS and I am switching my code from dynamic to strongly typed.

I have been looking at replacing `CurrentPage.Id` with `Model.Content.Id` however visual studio is underlining the `Id` with a red line with the message:

> Cannot convert method group 'id' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did
>   you intend to invoke method?

Besides this it is working fine.

I tried using `Model.Content.Id()` which removes the red line however it throws the error:

> CS1501: No overload for method 'Id' takes 0 arguments

Should I just use `Model.Content.Id` anyway? Can this visual studio 'error' be ignored? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That is all the code, I am just printing it straight to the page as `@Model.Content.Id` and it returns the page Id.

Comment: What is this view inheriting from? UmbracoViewPage or Umbraco Template Page?

Comment: @ProNotion `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Content>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.Content.Id` is correct, `Model.Content` is an `IPublishedContent` object with an `Id` property

To make intellisense work you can add the following namespaces to the `web.config` located in the Views directory

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Umbraco.Web" />
    <add namespace="Umbraco.Core" />
    <add namespace="Umbraco.Core.Models" />
    <add namespace="Umbraco.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="umbraco" />
    <add namespace="Examine" />
    <add namespace="Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels" />        
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Thank-you, I already have all these added but it is still underlined... at least I know it is correct!